# Autotools ./configure fails during config.status: executing depfiles commands in alpine due to incorrect MKDIR_P definition

Tags: autotools, alpine-linux

I am attempting to move a service previously created in a Debian container into Alpine to save space. I thought this would be easy, autotools/autoconf are supported in Alpine! I was wrong, so very wrong.

After running `autoreconf -vfi` in our project root, I would then run `./configure`. This step would fail during the `executing depfiles commands` in the `config.status` script because for some reason the MKDIR_P variable was defined to `-d`. Reading from the docs [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Particular-Programs.html) it appears that this is related to using `install` instead of `mkdir`.

I do not understand why the `install` form appears to be chosen, because `mkdir -p` is definitely valid in my container. Our `configure.ac` does not include any of the macros included in the first reference.

Comment: Note that running `autoreconf` is ***not*** a normal or recommended part of building an Autotools project from a proper source distribution (which should already provide `configure` and all other Autotools-built files) on a build host supported by the package.  It can and sometimes does cause problems, though it's unclear whether that's responsible for your particular issue.

Comment: Yeah, ideally the codeowner would have done that since they had the most knowledge about the project. For this instance though I am starting from a `configure.ac` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I have been able to fix this is to change the `./configure` step.

`autoreconf -vfi && ./configure MKDIR_P="mkdir -p"`

This forces the MKDIR_P variable to = "mkdir -p" during the subsequent build steps.

#### Update

After looking into the `configure.ac` script some more, it appears that a line specifying the location of the aux directory, `AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR`, is the cause. Removing this seems to provide sane results for a suitable `MKDIR_P` value.